# Calculating % in VBA Code For Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to calculate % in Excel Sheet via VBA code as follows:

```
.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((ISBLANK(RC[-2])=FALSE),IF((ISERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-1]),0,RC[-2]/RC[-1]),"""")"
```

But it gives me an error.

If the `RC[-2]` column is blank, the result of the % column should be blank, if not, I need to check if the denominator is 0 in order to avoid division by zero error (`#DIV/0!`
 is populated if the denominator is zero)

Can somebody please point out where is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss a closing bracket - this will probably work better (not sure if it will do what you want though!):

```
"=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-2])=FALSE,IF(ISERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-1]),0,RC[-2]/RC[-1]),"""")"
```

Or even more readable:

```
"=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-2]),"""",IF(ISERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-1]),0,RC[-2]/RC[-1]))"
```